# How to return 2 items from 2 different tables within 1 query in Spring JPA?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, stored-functions

I have a postgres query within my springboot app that needs to return a list with each element (being an array) containing 2 items from 2 different tables. The entities for each table are as follows:

*table_one:*

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "table_one")
@Table(name = "table_one")
public class TableOne {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    private String commonField;
    private String type;
    private String specId;
}
```

*table_two:*

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "table_two")
@Table(name = "table_two")
public class TableTwo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    private String commonField;
    private String name;
}
```

Now, these tables are connected and the output of 1 would be required to get the 2nd item. The 1st item would be of type `TableOne` and the 2nd item would be of type `List<TableTwo>`. The 2nd item contains a list of `TableTwo` objects that relate to a `TableOne` objects that have the same `type` field.

My initial idea was to use spring [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) (I used [this](https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/) guide to create one). However, it turns out that projections cannot seem to return collections.

Then I decided to create [CTEs](https://learnsql.com/blog/cte-with-examples/) and use them instead. My query is as so:

```
@Query(value = "WITH subset_items AS (SELECT table_two.common_field FROM table_two WHERE table_two.name = ‘beans’), item_one AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_one WHERE table_one.common_field in subset_items)
SELECT *,* FROM item_one , subset_items WHERE subset_items.common_field in (SELECT table_one.common_field FROM table_one WHERE table_one.type = item_one.type)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> myMethod();
```

However, I hit a road block and while investigating, I found out that CTEs cannot be used as part of a WHERE clause (in my case my 2nd CTE uses the 1st one). From one I can tell, there is no tricks to make it work.

My next idea was to make use of `CREATE FUNCTION` with return type of table. I used [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to make my query and end up with this:

```
    @Query(value=
        "CREATE FUNCTION subset_items() RETURNS TABLE(common_field text) AS " +
            "$$ SELECT table_two.common_field FROM table_two WHERE table_two.name = 'beans' $$ LANGUAGE sql; " +
        "CREATE FUNCTION ent_id() RETURNS TABLE(common_field text,spec_id text) AS " +
            "$$ SELECT common_field,spec_id FROM table_one WHERE table_one.common_field in subset_items$$ LANGUAGE sql; " +
        "SELECT *, * FROM item_one , subset_items WHERE subset_items.common_field in " +
            "(SELECT table_one.common_field FROM table_one WHERE table_one.type = item_one.type)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> myMethod();
```

However, I ran into an exception that I cannot solve when starting my app. It is as bellow:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

So my question is as follows: what causes this exception? Did I do something wrong when creating my functions?

Alternatively, I would be happy to try another approach. I also think that the query can be simplified where a few simple subqueries will do the trick but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it but it  is still a normal table and must be treated as such:

```sql
WITH subset_items AS (
    SELECT table_two.common_field 
      FROM table_two 
     WHERE table_two.name = ‘beans’)
    , item_one AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT * 
          FROM table_one 
         WHERE table_one.common_field IN 
            (SELECT common_field 
               FROM subset_items))
    SELECT *, * 
      FROM item_one, subset_items 
     WHERE subset_items.common_field IN (
        SELECT table_one.common_field 
          FROM table_one 
         WHERE table_one.type = item_one.type)
```

Comment: Yes that indeed allows for CTEs to be used. Not part of original question but would you happen to know by any chance how can I return the results of CTEs as tables? What I mean by that is my query atm returns each field as an entry of my Object[] array (as oppose to collecting all fields of item_one table in one java Object and all fields of subset_items into another java Object).

Comment: A cte  is only a method to create temporary tables the rest is like a normal select, and for the oms  it make absolutely no difference as it returns recordsset

Comment: I see, but still not sure how to return 2 collections of columns as my output. I guess I can ask a separate question. Ta!